# 2nd post different layout

Tags: posts

As a designer I'm the ***hole who makes different layouts for posts to make a page more different. Due to this, I'm trying to create the following:

[image]

This is the code I'm currently trying to fix.

[EDIT] I've got the styles working, but now the content is being duplicated [/EDIT]

```
<?php
$query = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => array( 'innovation_lab' ) ) );


while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
$i=0;
    if ($i%3==0) echo '

    <div class="row border">

    ';

      echo '      
            <div class="col-lg-6">

                <a href="'; the_permalink(); echo '">';    
                echo '<h1>'; the_title(); echo '</h1></a><p>';


                                    foreach((get_the_category()) as $childcat) {
                                    if (cat_is_ancestor_of(10, $childcat)) {
                                    echo '<a href="'.get_category_link($childcat->cat_ID).'" class="category small">';
                                    echo $childcat->cat_name . '</a>  &nbsp;&#47;&nbsp;  ';
                                    }}


            echo '</p><p>';
            echo excerpt(60);
            echo '</p>';


      echo '';

          echo '<p><a href="'; the_permalink(); echo '" class="btn btn btn-readmore" >Lees meer</a></p>

          </div>

          <div class="col-lg-6">
          <p class="pull-right">';

                         the_post_thumbnail('', array('class' => 'pull-right img-responsive img-samenvatting'));

                         echo '</p></div></div>';




    if ($i%3==2) echo '



    ';

      echo '

                  <div class="row border"><div class="col-lg-6">';


      the_post_thumbnail('', array('class' => 'pull-right img-responsive img-samenvatting'));

      echo '</div>


            <div class="col-lg-6">

                <a href="'; the_permalink(); echo '">';    
                echo '<h1>'; the_title(); echo '</h1></a><p>';


                                    foreach((get_the_category()) as $childcat) {
                                    if (cat_is_ancestor_of(10, $childcat)) {
                                    echo '<a href="'.get_category_link($childcat->cat_ID).'" class="category small">';
                                    echo $childcat->cat_name . '</a>  &nbsp;&#47;&nbsp;  ';
                                    }}


            echo '</p><p>';
            echo excerpt(60);
            echo '</p>';


      echo '';

          echo '<p><a href="'; the_permalink(); echo '" class="btn btn btn-readmore" >Lees meer</a></p>

          </div></div>';


    if ($i%3==3) echo '</div>'; 


    $i++;
endwhile;


?>
```

PS: Please don't judge my PHP..

Comment: This question is about generic PHP/HTML/CSS not specific to Wordpress, so it is out of the scope of this site. Anyway, here my advice: use the same layout (HTML markup) but [apply different CSS stlye to even/odd rows](http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/evenodd.html).

Comment: "Please don't judge my PHP" -- well... that spoils the fun. :) The PHP is the problem though, and as already noted pure PHP is off topic.

Comment: @cybnet & s_ha_dum , This is WordPress related as it's important for theming, right? I guess I'm not only frontend designer wishing to use this..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok solution found. I forgot to use the {} and now it works. Here goes:

```
<?php
$query = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => array( 'custom_post_type' ) ) );

$i = 0;
while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
    if ($i%2==0){ 

    echo '1st post here';


    }

    if ($i%2==1){   

    echo '2nd post here';       

          }

    $i++;

endwhile;

?>
```

Comment: You can also use if else, instead of two if's